# tf.Dataset.from_tensor_slices performance problem

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

For my input fn, I am filling the tf.Data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array1, np.array2, np.array3)

And I am parsing them by calling dataset.map. as a result I am returning my dataset.

I would understand the initialization of the dataset can be slow but when I call the tf.estimator train_and_evaluate function to train and evaluate the model, it is performing very bad. Probably it is populating data in each epoch. What would be the reason? How can I overcome this problem. What would be your recommendations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing a c++ Python roundtrip. If you can try to avoid using numpy as much as you can. Maybe try using tf records.

What exactly are you doing in your map function?

Comment: I am just creating a feature and label dictionaries in the map function

Answer (score 0):

To increase the efficiency of your data ingestion you can try three different things:

1. Use Tfrecords.
2. Use a generator function
3. Use a custom dataset reader

Using tf records is probably the most easiest and most efficient way to tackle this problem. It provides great speed up once you converted your dataset into a tf record dataset

If you do not want to convert your dataset you are stuck with two more methods:

Using a generator and create a dataset using the tf dataset.from_generator function ( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset ). This will slow down your data ingestion since your are not using a optimized C++ reader, but with a little bit of numpy magic you can create quite okay readers. Use this method for if you want to take a quick look into your dataset.

If you want similar speeds compared to tfrecords you have to create a custom reader for the tf dataset. You can find an explanation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/new_data_formats 
For this to work you need a little bit of c++ knowledge.

All in all:

Tf record if you want to convert

from_generator if you want to go quick and dirty and performance is not the most important

own reader function if you want to do it right

I hope I was able to help out a little bit :)